# How to use rlang to extract list value by name?

Tags: r, list, rlang

I am passing the name of a list element to a function as a string. I want to be able to extract the list element value by this name so I can use it dynamically with my function. Here is an MRE:

```
# function to reset list element at 
# 'tmp'. List files in folder which is 
# the list element value at 'tmp'.
x <- function(my_list, here){
  my_list %>% 
    purrr::list_modify(
      !!rlang::sym(here) := base::list.files(path = .$here)
  )
}

# folder with great files in it.
l <- base::list(tmp = 'folder/')

x(l, 'tmp')
```

I have tried `rlang::sym` with the `here` element, but to no avail. I believe I need `.$`, but maybe magrittr::aliases could be used instead. What is a solution?

Expected result:

```
# function to reset list element at 
# 'tmp'. List files in folder which is 
# the list element value at 'tmp'.
x <- function(my_list, here){
  my_list %>% 
    purrr::list_modify(
      !!rlang::sym(here) := base::list.files(path = .$tmp)
  )
}

# folder with great files in it.
l <- base::list(tmp = 'folder/')

x(l, 'tmp')
```

Comment: Do you consider using `here` pacakge or may be `file.path`

Comment: I think you want `!!rlang::sym(here) :=  base::list.files(path = .[[here]])`. But it's unclear to me exactly what the desired output is supposed to be. It would be easier if you made a reproducible example that didn't depend on local files and folders being present to run and test the function.

Comment: Yes, I finally used magrittr's alias for .[[here]]. You were right!